# Не получается спарсить роли из токена

Tags: golang, jwt

При регистрации пользователя ему дается роль и в последующем их может становиться больше, то есть логика такая, что у одного пользователя может быть несколько ролей. При входе на сайт бэк делает запрос к бд,  где вытаскивает все роли, а также id пользователя, после генерит токен и отсылает на клиента. В дальнейшем этот токен используется для получения доступа к эндпоинтам REST API.
Была написана функция, в которой десириализую токен и забираю роли, в ручках потом просто проверяется, есть у этих ролей доступ к ручкам.
Ниже приведен код того как генерится токен:

```
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
            "user_id": existingUserID, // получаем запросом к бд
            "roles":   roles, // получаем запросом к бд
        })
        log.Printf("user_id: %v\n", existingUserID)
        log.Printf("roles: %v\n", roles)
        tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("SECRET_KEY")))
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(500, gin.H{"message": "Failed to generate token", "error": err})
            return
        }
```

Далее код, того как десиаризую токен и пытаюсь вытащить роли из него:

```
package auth

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func CheckUserRole(tokenString string) ([]string, error) {

    log.Printf("Received token: %s", tokenString)

    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(os.Getenv("SECRET_KEY")), nil
    })
    if err != nil || !token.Valid {
        log.Printf("Error parsing token: %v", err)
        return nil, errors.New("Invalid token")
    }

    claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("Error getting claims from token")
        return nil, errors.New("Invalid token claims")
    }

    roles, ok := claims["roles"].([]string)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("Roles not found in token")
        return nil, errors.New("Roles not found in token")
    }

    log.Printf("User roles: %v", roles)

    return roles, nil
}
```

В общем проблема заключается в том, что не находит роли в токене: Roles not found in token.
Почему не знаю, уже миллион отладочных выводов сделал, все роли правильно определяются.
Вот вывод клэймов:
Claims: map[roles:[22 18] user_id:9]
скорее всего как-то неправильно пытаюсь их занести в roles, но вроде все правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вашего кода в том, что `claims["roles"]` - это объект типа `[]any`, и его нельзя привести к типу `[]string`. Нужно извлекать каждый элемент и приводить его к типу `string`.

Вот пример:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    jwt "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func main() {
    token_src := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "user_id": "9",                 // получаем запросом к бд
        "roles":   []string{"8", "22"}, // получаем запросом к бд
    })
    tokenString, err := token_src.SignedString([]byte("secret"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte("secret"), nil
    })
    if err != nil || !token.Valid {
        log.Printf("Error parsing token: %v", err)
        panic("Invalid token")
    }

    claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("Error getting claims from token")
        panic("Invalid token claims")
    }

    claims_roles, ok := claims["roles"]
    log.Printf("Roles: %#v, type %T", claims_roles, claims_roles)
    if !ok {
        panic("no roles object")
    }
    _, ok = claims_roles.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("unexpected roles object: expected []interface{}, got %T", claims_roles))
    }
    roles := []string{}
    for _, r := range claims_roles.([]interface{}) {
        role, ok := r.(string)
        if !ok {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("unexpected role object %#v: expected string, got %t", r, r))
        }
        roles = append(roles, role)
    }
    log.Printf("User roles: %v", roles)

}
```

Но на самом деле в `jwt` есть поддержка типизированных объектов `Claims` - парсер за вас приведёт все типы и разложит по нужным местам

```go
type RoleClaims struct {
    UserId uint   `json:"user_id"`
    Roles  []uint `json:"roles"`
}

func (rc RoleClaims) Valid() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    token_src := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
        RoleClaims{
            UserId: 9,
            Roles:  []uint{8, 22},
        },
    )
    tokenString, err := token_src.SignedString([]byte("secret"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var token_claims RoleClaims
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &token_claims, func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte("secret"), nil
    })
    if err != nil || !token.Valid {
        log.Printf("Error parsing token: %v", err)
        panic("Invalid token")
    }
    log.Printf("Claims: %#v", token_claims)

    log.Printf("User roles: %v", token_claims.Roles)
}
```

Функция `jwt.ParseWithClaims` извлечёт `claims` из токена и распарсит их как объект типа `RoleClaims`, результат сохранит в `token_claims`. И вам не нужно будет приводить типы, разбирать отдельные элементы. Всё будет сделано автоматически.